# grep while read line alternatives

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a log file.log:

```
toto string1 tata string2 tito string3
tata tati string3
titi string1 tato string2 tati toto
.....
tutu string1 tita string2 tita string3
```

I need to extract string1, string2 and string3 from every line in the file.
The lines could contain one or two or the three strings.

My first try using while read LINE do grep:

```
while read line; do 
z_string1=`echo $line | egrep 'string1' | cut -f2 xxx | cut -f1 xxxx`
z_string2=`echo $line | egrep 'string2' | cut -f2 xxx | cut -f1 xxxx`
z_string3=`echo $line | egrep 'string3' | cut -f2 xxx | cut -f1 xxxx`
echo "$z_string1,$z_string2,$z_string3" >> results.csv
done < file.log
```

This works as expected but it's not optimized at all and it's very slow.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you want to extract just stringX or the whole line containing stringX?

Comment: I want to extract just stringX

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous ways to achieve this.  Since you seem to prefer shell, you should have a look at [awk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), which is basically designed to do just this.

Perl is also intended for exactly this sort of task.  A simple script with a few regexps to match your search terms, followed by a print.

- [Perl Intro - Regular Expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Regular-expressions)

Answer (score 1):

try `grep -oE "string[0-9]" file.log >> results.csv`  `-o` flag gives only the matching part as an output

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see your string pattern is changing columns:

```
toto string1 tata string2 tito **string3**
tata tati string3
titi string1 tato string2 tati toto
.....
tutu string1 tita string2 tita string3
```

2nd line is 3rd column the rest are column2 so there is no point in relying on column number for output as can be seen here:

```
awk -v pattern="string" '{cols=NF; if ( (cols == 6 ) && ($2 ~ pattern))   { print $2 " " $4 " " $6 } }' test.txt 
string1 string2 string3
string1 string2 toto
string1 string2 string3
```

so..

you could use this or parts of this for your solution

```
    awk -v p1="string1" -v p2="string2" -v p3="string3" 'BEGIN { c1=0; c2=0; c3=0; }
 {if (( $0 ~ p1) || ( $0 ~ p2) || ($0 ~ p3 ))  { 
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if ( $i ~ p1)   { print $i; c1++; 
        } else if  ( $i ~ p2)   { print $i; c2++; 
        } else if ( $i ~ p3)   { print $i; c3++; }
   }  } 
   } END{ print p1"_count:" c1 " "p2"_count:" c2"  "p3"_count:"c3}  ' test.txt
```

This produces:

```
string1
string2
string3
string3
string1
string2
string1
string2
string3
string1_count:3 string2_count:3  string3_count:3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `bash` regular expression matching to capture the string (if present),
then print them. I assume from your example that you just want to print an
empty string if no match is found, so I preserve that behavior.

```
while read line; do
    [[ $line =~ (string1) ]]; printf "%s," "$BASH_REMATCH"
    [[ $line =~ (string2) ]]; printf "%s," "$BASH_REMATCH"
    [[ $line =~ (string3) ]]; printf "%s\n" "$BASH_REMATCH"
done
```

This may not be as fast as a `perl` or `awk` solution, but should be an improvement over your original, as no additional processes need to be created; everything is done in `bash`.